# How to create template file for skinr module in drupal?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have installed skinr module. In that there is an option to select **Template Files.**

I don't have idea how to implement it.

**1. How Should i need to create a template file for this?**

**2. Where it should be saved?**

**3. How it will get the template file by default?**

**4. How can this be achieved?**

Here is the screenshot below.. Thanks in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the template in the .info file of your theme.

If you read [this article](http://pingv.com/blog/an-introduction-to-stylin-efficiency-with-the-skinr-module) first, then I think that the instructions [here](http://drupal.org/node/578574#custom-templates) are easy to understand